# Microsoft Edge window.getSelection() returns incorrect result

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I am experiencing this with Microsoft Edge; Chrome behaves as expected.

The issue is that when the last character is included in the selection, window.getSelection().anchorOffset or window.getSelection().focusOffset returns 1 when using Edge. (Which function returns the value 1 depends on which direction the selection is made.) Referring to the example below, I expect the value to be 225 -- which is what Chrome returns. When the selection includes anything other than the last character, the result is correct. Any guidance as to a workaround or different approach would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<style>
    #mydiv {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    mydiv.addEventListener("dragstart", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var s = window.getSelection().anchorNode.textContent;
        var anchorOffset = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
        var focusOffset = window.getSelection().focusOffset;
        myresults.textContent = "anchorOffset: " + anchorOffset + " focusOffset: " + focusOffset;
    });
    var myresults = document.getElementById("myresults");
</script>

<div id="mydiv" class="mydiv" contenteditable="true">Microsoft Edge: Select a portion of text here then drag it. The selection anchorOffset and focusOffset will display. Do it again, but this time make sure the last character is included in the selection. One of the values will be 1!</div>
<div id="myresults"></div>
```

Comment: From what I'm seeing if you select a word, or even a few words but not an entire line it works as expected. I can't really think of a workaround based on the precise code. I highly recommend filing a bug at bugs.microsoftedge.com so they can get it fixed. What is the use case you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
function getSelectedText() {
  var txt = '';

  if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection();
  }
  else if (document.getSelection) {
    txt = document.getSelection();
  }
  else if (document.selection) {
    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  else return; 

  return txt;
}
```

The browser compatibility of this method can be seen below.

**Reference:**

[DocumentOrShadowRoot.getSelection() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/getSelection#Browser_Compatibility)

https://caniuse.com/#search=window.getSelection

Besides, if you want to check if the browser is Edge, you can do below.

```
window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. However I get the same result.

Comment: @Len White, please see update function, which is cross browser method.